# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs in react native

Tags: android, react-native, compiler-errors

I have set the exported value to true then also I am getting the following error.

Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android: exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works for react native apps, but in general, in Android you have your own `manifest` + you have a `merged manifest` that is a combination of your own manifest and of manifests of all libraries you're using.
It is possible that one of your libraries is not specifying an explicit value there. Most of the time, if you upgrade your dependencies to the newest versions, it should help.
Try setting your target sdk to 30, check how the merged manifest looks like (this way you will see which `android: exported` is missing) and you will know which dependency needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following lines in my project and it solved my error.

Android -> App -> Build.gradle

```
android {   
   configurations{
      all.exclude module:'conceal'
      all.exclude module:'bcprov-jdk15on'   
   }   
} 
dependencies{   
    implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0" 
}
```